# Complexity of inserting into priority queue

Tags: queue, big-o, complexity-theory, priority-queue

Consider the following code that pops the first 2 elements from priority queue, adds them and inserts the sum back to priority queue.

```
while (pq.size() > 1)
{
    // Extract shortest two ropes from pq
    int first = pq.top();
    pq.pop();
    int second = pq.top();
    pq.pop();

    // Connect the ropes: update result and
    // insert the new rope to pq
    res += first + second;
    pq.push(first + second);
}
```

It is known that inserting into priority queue for n elements is O(nlogn) operation. But lets say priority queue is implemented as an array.
Won't it become O(N*N) operation.
Or what will be the complexity for the above code for n elements.

Answer (score 2):

A well-implemented priority queue will insert elements in O (log n) amortised steps per insertion. A well-implemented priority queue is quite likely to use an array, with the array elements arranged according to the heapsort algorithm.

Comment: But if it is implemented as  an array we also need to shift the elements right to make space for the insertion. So in that case won't it result to O(N*N) for N elements?

Comment: @AshishChopra, no, priority queue is implemented using a heap, which, in turn, is implemented using an array. Inserting an element into a heap is just series of swaps. Take a look at [heapsort](https://orrsella.gitbooks.io/soft-eng-interview-prep/content/topics/algorithms-examples.html)